# inspect.py file in folder makes importing pandas not work anymore

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pip, package

I am sorry if this is a silly question but I came across a wierd behaviour. I have a folder with some files, one of them named inspect.py
[image]

However, if I change the name inspect.py to somethingelse.py, importing pandas starts working.
[image]

I would really like to understand why this is. I assume it has something to do with the module called inspect which (I THINK??) comes by default installed.

Can anyone help me understand this, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking a `np.ma.core.py` I see

```
import builtins
import inspect
import operator
import warnings
import textwrap
import re
```

These are all base Python modules.  Your local `inspect.py` gets imported instead, which messes with the importing the rest of `np.ma.core`, and `numpy` in turn.  And `pandas` depends on `numpy`.

Comment: Thank you very much @hpaulj! That makes a lot of sense.